# Get parent ID from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `@CATS` and `@NEWCATS`

```
declare @CATS table (_Group int, _Name nvarchar(50))
declare @NEWCATS table (_Name nvarchar(50))

insert into @CATS (_Group, _Name) values (1, 'Siamese'), (1, 'Japanese'), (2, 'Siamese'), (2, 'Japanese'), (2, 'Russian')
insert into @NEWCATS (_Name) values ('Siamese'), ('Japanese')
```

I want to find if there exists a _Group in @CATS containing **exactly** the rows from @NEWCATS (e.g. 'Siamese' and 'Japanese').

In this example, I want to return _Group=1, but not _Group=2 (because _Group=2  contains 'Russian').

That is, to complete this:

```
declare @Group int
select TOP 1 @Group = _Group
from ...
```

Note: There is no guarantee that the groups are unique, that's why TOP 1.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
select CATS._Group
  from CATS
  left join NEWCATS on NEWCATS._Name = CATS._Name
 group by CATS._Group
having sum(case when NEWCATS._Name is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If they were real tables and there were indexes, other ways using different access plans could produce faster results.

---

**Update**

Given new requirement that all rows in `NEWCATS` must be referenced:

```
select CATS._Group
  from CATS
  left join NEWCATS on NEWCATS._Name = CATS._Name
 group by CATS._Group
having sum(case when NEWCATS._Name is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
   and count(*) = ( select count(*) from NEWCATS )
```

Comment: See demo: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386931 You have to use table `NEWCATS` not `CATS` in `CASE`.

Comment: Good. You could skip the "else 0" part.

Comment: @lad2025 DOH! I knew that. Thanks. Good catch.

Comment: @trincot You can't skip `else 0`, because if no nulls are found, all results of the `case` would be `null`, and `sum(null)` is `null`, and `null = 0` is false, so you would never get a row back from the query.

Comment: There is a problem with this query, if NEWCATS has additional rows.
Query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386938/cats

Comment: @PålThingbø I guess your interpretation of "**only** the rows" is different from mine. Sounds like you meant "**exactly** the rows" or maybe "**only all** the rows", as in no more and no less.

Comment: Yes I did. Was looking for the SQL equivalent of "if and only if", but you got it. Question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT _group
FROM @CATS
EXCEPT
SELECT c._group
FROM @CATS c
LEFT JOIN @NEWCATS nc
  ON nc._Name = c._Name
WHERE nc._Name IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386935)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT _Group FROM @CATS) AS c
  CROSS JOIN @NEWCATS nc
)
SELECT DISTINCT _group
FROM @CATS
EXCEPT
SELECT COALESCE(c._Group, cte._Group) AS _Group
FROM @CATS c
FULL JOIN cte
  ON c._Group = cte._Group
 AND c._Name = cte._Name
WHERE c._Name IS NULL
   OR cte._Name IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386953)**</kbd>

Comment: This runs into the same problem as below, if newcats has additional rows: 
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386941

Thanks for pointing me to EXCEPT, never heard of it. Maybe I could use INTERSECT. Will try.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks a lot. Although that crossjoin is horrible if @CATS gets big.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to require an exact match, so that a found group has exactly all, but no other names as present in the `@NEWCATS` table:

```
SELECT    @CATS._Group
FROM      @CATS
LEFT JOIN @NEWCATS ON @CATS._Name = @NEWCATS._Name
GROUP BY  @CATS._Group
HAVING    COUNT(DISTINCT @NEWCATS._Name)
        = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT _Name) FROM @NEWCATS);
```